# How to show this sigma-algebra is equal to the borel sigma-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

I have a question how to solve this problem.

We have $\mathbb{R}$ with the borel sigma-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ and $f_x: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f_x(y)=2x-y$.

We define $\Sigma = \{B \in \mathcal{B}: f_x(B) \in \mathcal{B}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

The question is: show that $\Sigma=\mathcal{B}$

I already proved that $\Sigma$ is a sigma-algebra and I believe $\mathcal{B}\subset \Sigma$, because of the definition of $\Sigma$.  But i'm not sure and I have no idea how I can show that $\Sigma$ is contained in the borel sigma-algebra.

Comment: Note that $\Sigma$ is defined to be a subset of $\mathcal{B}$ also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a family of sets such that $\mathcal{B}=\sigma(\mathcal{G})$. That is, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra should be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains every set in $\mathcal{G}$. If you can show that $\mathcal{G}\subseteq \Sigma$, you get $\mathcal{B}=\sigma(\mathcal{G})\subseteq \Sigma\subseteq\mathcal{B}$ and therefore $\mathcal{B}=\Sigma$. By definition of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, letting $\mathcal{G}$ consist of all open sets would work. But every open set of reals is a countable union of open intervals, so you can take $\mathcal{G}$ to consist of all open intervals.

So all you have to do is to show that every open interval is in $\Sigma$.